# Ruby: CSV to YAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, rubygems, yaml

I have the following csv example:

```
en.activerecord.models.admin_user.one;Guide
en.activerecord.models.admin_user.other;Guides
en.simple_captcha.placeholder;Type here
```

Is there a ruby gem or method to turn it into a Yaml file:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    models:
      admin_user:
        one: Guide
        other: Guides
  simple_captcha:
    placeholder: Type here
```

I'm still trying (using tree data model) but no results.

Any idea?

Comment: Convert your CSV to a hash, then write the hash to YAML. There are lots of questions about converting dot-delimited keys to nested hashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'yaml'  
hash = {}
file =  "en.activerecord.models.admin_user.one;Guide
en.activerecord.models.admin_user.other;Guides
en.simple_captcha.placeholder;Type here"
file.split("\n").each { |line| hash.deep_merge!(line.split(/\.|;/).reverse.inject() { |m,v| {v => m} }) }

puts YAML.dump(hash)
---
en:
  activerecord:
    models:
      admin_user:
        one: Guide
        other: Guides
  simple_captcha:
    placeholder: Type here
```

Comment: Thank you. hash should be {} in the beginning?

Comment: useful in converting files to localization yamls in rails.
Also please note the `deep_merge!` method is a rails method so can't be used directly in plain ruby script.